# Is it possible to add residuals as an explanatory variable to take away effects of correlated variables?

Tags: residuals, multicollinearity, nonlinear-regression

I have a response variable $y$ and two explanatory variables $x$ and $z$, but there's a strong correlation between $x$ and $z$. I'm interested in how $x$ and $z$ influence the value of $y$ respectively. And all of those relationships might be nonlinear.

I'm now considering this solution:

First, fit `z ~ x` with GAM and get the residual of this model $r$. Now consider the relationship between $y$ and $x,r$, i.e. to fit `y ~ x + r`.

If in this model, the effect of $r$ to $y$ is still significant, can I claim that $z$ has attribution to $y$ even though the influence from $x$ is taken away?

I'm new to statistics and I wonder if this solution will work or not and why?

Comment: This sounds like partial correlation.

Comment: @user2974951 Yep! But I'm not sure whether it works when I add the residuals directly to the model(GAM/GLM etc.) as an explanatory term.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would not simply run a multiple regression with a GAM in your case (which should take care of the confounding), but if you want to do it in a 2-step process, it's possible and you should look of "double machine learning" for references and justification.

Edit: for parametric models, a multiple regression is to be preferred also because it's not trivial to correctly forward the uncertainty of model 1 to model 2.

Comment: Very much thanks! The reason I don't fit `y ~ x + z` is that I'm worried about the possible concurvity. But I don't know much about the fitting method of GAM. Do you mean this kind of correlation between explanatory variables can be well settled by the model through, for example, its penalized loss function or some other technical details?

Comment: If you are worried about concurvity, you should fit the multiple gam, because the makes the uncertainty induced by concurvity explicit. Fitting the 2-stage model just hides the problem. This is what I meant above when I said "it's not trivial to correctly forward the uncertainty of model 1 to model 2."

Comment: I got it! One more question, how do you think about fitting a multivariate GAM `(y, z) ~ x`?

Comment: no, you fit y ~ x + z